# How to detect if a View is visible on the screen in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to detect if a `View` becomes visible on the screen in a `ScrollView`? I need to use it to possibly trigger animations.

Comment: just see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54180542/7858922
please check it out

Answer (score -3):

Check if you are able to get children of a parent view.
Suggest to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699918/react-native-how-do-we-know-what-child-element-is-contained-by-parent)